# Angular.js detect presence of bi-directional attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is self-explaining code, please check comments in html part:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
<div ng-controller="MCtrl">
  <!-- this should be "test:", OK -->
  <test></test>
  <br>
  <!-- this should be "test: Hello world!", OK -->
  <test custom-target="helloModel"></test>
  <br>
  <!-- this should be "test: Hello !", FAIL! -->
  <test custom-target="emptyModel"></test>
  <br>
</diV>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.helloModel = 'world';
    $scope.emptyModel = '';
}

myApp.directive('test', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
         customTarget: '='
      },
       template: '<span>test: <b ng-show="customTarget">Hello, {{customTarget}}!</b></span>'
   };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kMybm/34/

In short i need attribute `custom-target` to be optional and to be able to detect when it is missing.

**UPD:**

Currently found this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/kMybm/35/

Maybe there is better one.

Answer (score 1):

`b` tag in third example is not displayed at all because you've got ngShow on it, which evaluates to false when customTarget is empty string.